# What is the Image API of WordPress

Tags: python, image, wordpress, import, migration

I am writing a migrating script to move blog posts from an unknown blog to WordPress, and I want to host those images on WordPress. For the texts, I can write them into the ".wxr" file. I found some related topics saying importing pictures cannot be done automatically. Looking forward to any clarification.

p.s. If there is, please give a demo.

Answer (score -1):

There are plugins that help the second stage of your import. The idea is to (1) import your blog posts via wxr. Doing so will leave hotlinked images in blog posts, pointing to the old location.

At that point, (2) run a image migration plugin and it will hopefully do what you want it to (physically move file, insert as post attachment, rewrite image / a href).

One I used for blogger was [blogger image import](http://notions.okuda.ca/wordpress-plugins/blogger-image-import/)

For a less-standard blog migration, I mysql regexp'd for img tags and used wget to retrieve the files manually.